# Updating dictionary values deep in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to add a dictionary into dictionary. Where is my mistake?

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I expect to update my dictionary "myD'. At the moment it contains a set of keys with no values. I want to update the keys with values (other dictionaries) that I find in another dictionary.

```
input = {{"1":""},{"2":""},{"3":""}}
ExpectedOutput = {{"1":{"dd":"bb"}},{"2":{"dd":"bb"}},{"3":{"dd":"bb}"}}
```

dic2 is dictionary key. I believe it becomes a string when I call it. So lets say dic2 is string.

```
def fn():
    for key,value in d1.iteritems():
        if "data" == key:
            for dic2, value in value.iteritems():
                s1[dic2] = ""
                for k1 in value:
                    s1.update[dic2](k1) # <=============
```

I think it could be because of string?

Comment: I think more likely the error is because you're overwriting the value stored in `value` on the second loop

Comment: What errors you receive and what is expected output?

Comment: Why are you looping over `d1`? Why not just use `d1['data']`?

Comment: Please show us some sample input and what you expect your output to be

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `value`

```
for dic2, value in value.iteritems():
```

you are assigning `value` a new  value so `value.iteritems()` would fail

Comment: `value.iteritems()` will work fine - it's evaluated only once at the start of the loops. Providing the OP doesn't want the outer `value`, this should still work fine (although it's still bad practice)

Answer (score -1):

value.iteritems() it's wrong.
value is string, infact if i run your code i get:

```
for key, value in value.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the value of `d1`, which the OP hasn't told us

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand: is d1 a dictionary?

Comment: Probably, but there's nothing to say what type the values in it are.

Comment: `d1` could be a dictionary of dictionaries, in which case the line you have written in your answer would be perfectly correct (i.e. `value.iteritems()`, value is a dictionary).

Comment: Ah ok, you're both rigth, now i understand.
Thanks!